# How to use a link in TableTools instead of flash buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I'm trying to find a way to change the buttons on TableTools. I'd like to use my own customized links instead of the flash buttons. Is there a way I can do that? Any good resource teaching me how to make that modification and still able to use the functionalities, like button collection, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the creator](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7583/need-tabletools-export-functionality-to-work-without-flash./p1), the only way to get the TableTools export functionality is by using the Flash buttons.

> The other threads that you found should say that currently, no, this
>   is not an option that TableTools provides. The Flash option is used to
>   provide cross browser / platform ability to save files entirely on the
>   client-side - that option simply isn't available in older browsers
>   (IE6, IE7 etc) where there is no support for the data:// protocol and
>   local file system interaction options.
>
> It would most certainly be possible to add this ability to TableTools,
>   but I'm afraid I haven't yet had an opportunity to do so. It is on the
>   road map though.
>
> Allan

If you are interested in creating the export files server side, you may want to consider [the download (GET) plug-in](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/plug-ins#download) for TableTools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to override the existing buttons eg PDF/CSV etc or to create new custom buttons that have links to a url to get or post data. Here, I'm showing 2 methods with get methods:

For More info on Get & Post methods:

Visit: [Datatable tabletools GET/POST download method overrides](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/plug-ins#download)

**Code generated pdf is used because pdf output from tabletools on a table that have rows grouped by some column data is overlapped.**

1st to override PDF function and

2nd to create custom button.

**1. Override PDF function to fetch pdf from server code.**

```
/*Get Method table Tools - PDF - Overriding*/

    TableTools.BUTTONS.pdf = {
        "sAction": "text",
        "sTag": "default",
        "sFieldBoundary": "",
        "sFieldSeperator": "\t",
        "sNewLine": "<br>",
        "sToolTip": "",
        "sButtonClass": "DTTT_button_text",
        "sButtonClassHover": "DTTT_button_text_hover",
        //"sButtonText": "PDF",
        "mColumns": "all",
        "bHeader": true,
        "bFooter": true,
        "sDiv": "",
        "fnMouseover": null,
        "fnMouseout": null,
        "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig) {
            var oParams = this.s.dt.oApi._fnAjaxParameters(this.s.dt);
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.height = "0px";
            iframe.style.width = "0px";
            //iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl + "?" + $.param(oParams);
            iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl;//This is the URl you give in datatable Tabletools pdf override below
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        },
        "fnSelect": null,
        "fnComplete": null,
        "fnInit": null
    };

    /**/


/*Datatable initialisation*/
$(document).ready(function () {

oTable = $('#alternatecolor').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
            ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null],
            "bLengthChange": false, "bPaginate": false,
            "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
            //"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
              "csv", "xls",
              {
               /*PDF Override*/
              "sExtends": "pdf",
              "sButtonText": "PDF",
               //Custom url to fetch pdf report
              "sUrl": " report/PDFReportUsers/us/1"
          }
            ]
            }
        })
        /*Row grouping - optional*/
                .rowGrouping({ bExpandableGrouping: true,
                    bExpandSingleGroup: false,
                    iExpandGroupOffset: -1
                    //asExpandedGroups: [name]
                });

        /**/
    });  
});
```

**2. Custom button to fetch pdf from server code.**

```
        /*Get Method table Tools - Download custom button*/

        TableTools.BUTTONS.download= {
            "sAction": "text",
            "sTag": "default",
            "sFieldBoundary": "",
            "sFieldSeperator": "\t",
            "sNewLine": "<br>",
            "sToolTip": "",
            "sButtonClass": "DTTT_button_text",
            "sButtonClassHover": "DTTT_button_text_hover",
            //"sButtonText": "PDF",
            "mColumns": "all",
            "bHeader": true,
            "bFooter": true,
            "sDiv": "",
            "fnMouseover": null,
            "fnMouseout": null,
            "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig) {
                var oParams = this.s.dt.oApi._fnAjaxParameters(this.s.dt);
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.style.height = "0px";
                iframe.style.width = "0px";
                //iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl + "?" + $.param(oParams);
                iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            },
            "fnSelect": null,
            "fnComplete": null,
            "fnInit": null
        };

        /**/
$(document).ready(function () {

        oTable = $('#alternatecolor').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
            ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null],
            "bLengthChange": false, "bPaginate": false,
            "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
            //"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
              "csv", "xls"
                         , {
                              "sExtends": "download",
                              "sButtonText": "Download PDF",
                              "sUrl":     "admin/user/4/downloadfile"
                          }
            ]
            }
        })
        /*Row grouping - optional */
                .rowGrouping({ bExpandableGrouping: true,
                    bExpandSingleGroup: false,
                    iExpandGroupOffset: -1
                    //asExpandedGroups: [name]
                });

        /**/
    });
```

Comment: This code is same as their in dataTable website, ok fine... one help where you are generating pdf file in here, it seems you are creating a same iframe

Comment: @Suganthan, 
I've been using a url which returns pdf file as stream to user' browser.
To specify url of pdf generator: "sUrl":"admin/user/4/downloadfile"
DataTable loads the url by: iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl;