# Change onclick event to onhover on export option in datatables

Tags: datatables, export, onhover

I'm working with jQuery DataTables and TableTools extension in which my export option is working fine but I had requirement of instead of `onclick` I should show dropdown menu on hover of export button.

I tried all these [Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover) but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible because most of the TableTools functionality is implemented using Adobe Flash. Due to Flash security restrictions there is no way to programmatically trigger export to PDF or CSV other than let user click on the button.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537949/how-to-use-a-link-in-tabletools-instead-of-flash-buttons) for more details.